# How can I make a custom annotation automatically suppress unused warnings?

Tags: java, swing, annotations, lombok

I am doing an @AutoWired system similar to Spring, Lombok etc.

This type of thing:

```
@Instantiate
public TestClass testClass() { return new TestClass(); }

@Inject
private TestClass testClass;
```

Where these are of course in separate classes and the field would be equal to the method.

How can I make my @Inject annotation automatically suppress the unused warning, so it appears registered?

I poked round Swing source code but am none the wiser.

Comment: Is this "unused" warning from the compiler, or from the IDE? If the latter, you might have to write an IDE plugin to make the IDE aware of your annotations.